# OS X Dock is showing invalid icon for Calender app

Tags: dock, icon, calendar

I've noticed an issue. Are you facing the same?

How to resolve it? I tried removing the icon & added back but issue remains.

It is showing two `15` as a part of Calender itself. Is there something that I've missed for understanding dock icon for Calender app?

[image: Dock Calender Icon]

Comment: I'd be tempted to run the 10.10.3 combo updater over it, see if it clears up - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804?locale=en_us

Comment: Already updated to 10.10.3.

Comment: that's why I suggested running the combo - it will recheck everything since 10.10.0 & make sure it's up to date.

Comment: Tried that also. Not working :(

Comment: hmm… then I'm stumped, sorry